# how can I split a sentence into words using Visual C++

Tags: string, visual-c++, split

guys, let's say I a sentence

string sentence = "Hello, I like C++ programming language!";

and I want to put each word into an array of strings... I think I could use a delimiter

```
size_t space = sentence.find(" ");
string words[]; //putting individual words here
for(int i=0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
{
   words[i] = 
   //incrementing delimiter to next space here
}
```

any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string

Comment: Visual C++ is not a programming language. P.R. has already linked to answers on how to split a string in C++.

Answer (score 0):

you can use copy() in algorithm library

```
string s("Your String");
istringstream iss(s);
vector<string> words;
copy (istream_iterator(iss),istream_iterator(),back_inserter(words));
```

The code should be like that, and i think using Vector is better than an array of strings

Comment: It ONLY takes space as a delimeter